# Laravel eloquent multiple levels of relations

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Alright so I am basically trying to retrieve all animal_registry codes based on a user ID.

Idea is that
1 user has many jobs.
**Jobs** are consisted of many "**Jobs data**". 
**Jobs data** has many "**Animal registry**" entries.

These are my relations
[Image relations link (click)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwUYx.png)

And these are my relations in Laravel

```
class User
{
    public function jobs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\RegistryJobs', 'employee', 'id');
    }
}


class RegistryJobs extends Model
{
    protected $table = "registry_jobs";

    protected function jobsData()
    {
        $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\AnimalRegistry', 'App\Models\RegistryJobsData', 'id', 'animal_registry_id');
    }
}

class RegistryJobsData extends Model
{
    protected $table = "registry_jobs_data";

    public function jobs()
    {
        $this->belongsTo('App\Models\RegistryJobs', 'id', 'registry_jobs_id');
    }

    public function animals()
    {
        $this->hasMany('App\AnimalRegistry', 'id', 'animal_registry_id');
    }
}

class AnimalRegistry extends Model
{
    protected $table = "animal_registry";

}
```

And now I am trying to query it from a controller in a way

```
$data = User::whereHas('jobs', function ($query)  {
    $query->where('id', 1);
})->get();
```

But I am unable to access the properties from the animal_registry.

Comment: Not sure what level the question is at but are you looking for `User::with('jobs')->whereHas() ...`? Of course this would include all the related jobs and not just the one meeting the condition in the inner query.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this :

```
 public function animals(){
     return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Registry_Jobs_data','App\Registry_Jobs', 'employee', 
    'registry_jobs_id', 'id' ,'id')->join('//Do the joining')->select();
 }
```

Check the `hasManyThrough` i am not sure..